# Spark yarn return exit code not updating as failed in webUI - spark submit

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing

I'm running spark jobs through YARN with Spark submit , after my spark job failing the job is still showing status as **SUCCEED** instead of **FAILED**. how can I return exit code as failed state from code to the YARN?

How can we send yarn different application code status from the code?

Comment: Which version are you using? For instance this bug was supposed to be fixed in 1.2.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3877

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that. I have experienced the same behavior with [spark-1.6.2](/questions/tagged/spark-1.6.2), but after analyzing the failures, I don't see any obvious way of sending a "bad" exit code from my application.

Comment: No @KSNidhin, but I didn't investigate after answering this question. I see that you read my answer, but didn't upvote-any reason for that? :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried sending a non-zero exit code within the code using

```
System.exit(1);
```

which did not work as expected and @gsamaras mentioned the same in his answer. The following work around worked for me though , using try catch.

```
try{
}
catch {
      case e: Exception => {
      log.error("Error  " + e)
      throw e;
      }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, fixed this by changing deploy mode from client to cluster. If deploy mode is client, then state will always be FINISHED. Refer https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3627